# Find maximum of a function that is a maximum of functions

Tags: matlab, optimization

I would like to solve the following problem:

> x* = argmin f( max_{j=1,...,J} g_j(x)),

where `f` and `g_j` are known smooth, convex functions, and `x` is a scalar. I also have analytical gradients of `f` and `g_j`.  Is it possible to use `fminunc` (using Newton method) or another solver in MatLab to find the solution?  Obviously `max_{j=1,...,J} g_j(x)` is not differentiable (unless there is a `k` such that `g_k(x) >= g_j(x)` for all `j`), but it is sub-differentiable.  Therefore, I cannot use `fminunc` directly, as it requests the gradient of the objective function.  If I can use `fminunc`, how would I proceed?

As an example, consider `f(x) = x`, `J=1,2`, `g_1(x) = (x-1)^2`, `g_j(x) = (x+1)^2`.  Then `max g_1, g_2` is the upper envelope of `g_1` and `g_2`.  The minimum is located at `x=0`.

Note: The function `fminimax` is close to what I want.  `fminimax` solves

> x* = argmin  max_{j=1,...,J} g_j(x).

Comment: The maximum of the combination is a maximum of one of the single functions....  The minimum is either a minimum of one of the single functions or at one of the breakpoints where two intersect.

Comment: `fminsearch` does not require the gradient of the objective function. It uses the Nelder-Mead simplex algorithm

Comment: The extra composition complicates things a bit.

Comment: AVK: I would like to use gradient information to speed up convergence.  You are correct that `fminsearch` uses the simplex method.  I had `fminunc` or `fmincon` using Newton method in mind.  I have edited the question to reflect this, thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to use a derivative-based method? In my experience, for complex problems a combination of annealing + downhill simplex works best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have one potential solution to my problem. We can replace the maximum function with a smoothed or soft maximum, see [this article by John Cook](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/13/soft-maximum/).  In particular, we can approximate `max(x,y)` with the function `g(x,y;k) = log(exp(kx)+exp(ky))/y` (`k` is a tuning parameter).  Now the objective function is differentiable, so the Newton method can be applied (i.e., `fminunc`).